# How to parse ERail data into my android App

Tags: java, android, json

I have got a link for Getting data for Train Between Two Stations of Indian Railways. [This link shows the data as well as URL used](http://erail.in/rail/getTrains.aspx?Station_From=GWL&Station_To=NDLS&DataSource=0&Language=0), but I am not able to parse it in my android app. How to parse this kind of data in the App and display it in a nice look. Please someone help. And also what kind of data is this.? Is this JSON or something else.?

Comment: Usually in android data is parsed in JSON or in XML format ..This data does seem to be in any standard form that can be parsed using standard android classes

Comment: Do you know anything where I can get JSON data for Indian Railways site.?

Comment: this data is encrypted I think .. Thats because they have not kept it for public usage . Even if you find json data , make sure its available for public to access other wise other wise you will be technically be stealing data .

Answer (score 0):

Try using some Indian Railway **API** , instead of what you are doing .Since this data seems to be encrypted and is not in a standard format like JSON or XMl .It will be hard to parse.

Here are some API links that will be use full

http://www.railpnrapi.com/

http://pnrapi.alagu.net/

Hope it helps!

Comment: The First one is getting closed in February and the second one just provides for PNR. I have one more [link](http://pnrbuddy.com/hauth/api), but the problem is I am not able to generate the HMAC Key. Can you see [this](http://pnrbuddy.com/hauth/api?page=keys) and tell me how to get HMAC code for using this API.?

Comment: The procedure to generate HMAC key is specified here http://pnrbuddy.com/hauth/api?page=keys